# List all values between two given values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

If I have A1 = 4.5 and A2 = 7.5, how can is list every values (at 0.5 interval) between the two cells?

So A3 would display "5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0"?

How would I be able to display that output in excel for a list of values.

Comment: share your latest code attempt, start by having a `For` loop

Answer (score 1):

Use the Excel built in `Series` method.

[image]

```
Sub IncementByHalves()
'
' IncementByHalves Macro
'

'
    Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlLinear, Date:=xlDay, _
        Step:=0.5, Stop:=100, Trend:=False
End Sub
```